# SQL server express backend for ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server

I come from a linux/apache/php/mysql background. For my current project, I am forced to write web services using ASP.NET. I have installed visual studio and created an ASP.NET web service project. The web service I'm creating will use a SQL database backend. I see that visual studio installed "SQL Server Express 2008." I can see that there is a service called "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" that is running. My question is, how do I run queries against this database? Where's the front end? What tool do I use to create databases and tables? Is there something else I have to install?

I feel completely lost and my google-fu fails me. There are so many different SQL products from microsoft that I can't tell what is the easiest path to just having a simple database with tables I can query from my development machine. With MySQL, I would install the MySQL database, download MySQL query browser and start firing queries at it. How can I do that with Visual Studio/SQL Server Express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download SQL Server Management Studio from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en).  This is the GUI for working with SQL Server.  It will let you create databases, tables, stored procedures, etc. as well as writing queries and manually edit data in the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the Server Explorer tab in Visual Studio (by default on the right side, next to Solution Explorer) to add a data connection.  You can do most of the most common database tasks (create/query tables, create views, etc) from there.

Answer (score 0):

there's a command line tool that installs with SQL Server (all versions) called SQLCMD.exe, should be in your install path.

Visual Studio also lets you create dbs, run queries, look at table structures and data (including creating and deleting them, etc), you do that by opening your Server explorer window and making a connection to your local instance (.\SQLExpress by default).

Finally, as the other person mentioned, SQL Server Management Studio Express is a free download, and well worth the time it takes to install.